# Button click from one fragment to another?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating an app that will display cars. I am using the navigation drawer template and RelativeLayout.

I have one activity and a number of fragments.

Within my activity_main page (the page the user sees when the app first loads) I have a fragment (HomeFragment) with a picture of a car. I want to be able to click on the car and it takes me to another fragment where I can put more images of the same car on.

Does anyone know the code required to do this? I have heard I need to use FragmentManager but I'm not sure.

Comment: Could you pls post something which you have already done?

Comment: It's easy to navigate from one fragment to another. But after that there is lot more task.

Comment: start from here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I tried but the code is so long to place in here. Is there any part inparticualrly that you want me to post? Also, the part in which I need to know is what code I need. Thanks

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

1. Create interface `OnPictureOfCarClickListener`:

   ```
   public interface OnPictureOfCarClickListener {
      void onPictureOfCarClicked();
   }
   ```
2. Make your MainActivity implement `OnPictureOfCarClickListener`. It will require you `@Override` `onPictureOfCarClicked()` method:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onPictureOfCarClicked() {
      // this method will call when you click to the picture of car in your HomeFragment.
     // I will named fragment show more images is MoreCarFragment
     MoreCarFragment fragment = new MoreCarFragment();
     FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
     transaction.commit();
   }
   ```
3. In your HomeFragment:

   ```
   public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
      OnPictureOfCarClickListener mCallback;

     @Override
     public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
          mCallback = (OnPictureOfCarClickListener) activity;
       } catch (ClassCastException e) {
         throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
               + " must implement OnPictureOfCarClickListener");
       }

       // when you click to the picture of car
       public void onPictureOfCarClick(View view) {
         mCallback.onPictureOfCarClicked();
       }
   }
   ```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

follow an example of what I use in my project, each item in the case is a image in my layout.

```
 switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bottom_navigation_help:
           selectedFragment = HelpFragment.newInstance();
            break;

        case R.id.bottom_navigation_start:
           selectedFragment = WalletFragment.newInstance();
           break;
        case R.id.bottom_navigation_client:
           selectedFragment = CustomerListFragment.newInstance();
            break;

        case R.id.bottom_navigation_statistics:
           selectedFragment = StatisticsFragment.newInstance();
            break;

        case R.id.bottom_navigation_comunication:
            walletPresenter.checkCommunicationStep();
            break;
    }

    if (selectedFragment != null) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContent, selectedFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

You also need to add this to each 1 of your fragments

```
 @NonNull
public static Fragment newInstance() {
    return new ClientFragment();
}
```

Comment: I will give this a go and get back to you. Thanks!